# What is the difference between a flow chart and a UML activity diagram?

Tags: uml, difference, flowchart, activity-diagram

I know that an activity diagram is:

1. More simple;
2. More standardized;
3. Support concurrent flows.

compared to a flow chart.

But what are the possible reasons for using an activity diagram instead of a flow chart apart from those mentioned above?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An activity diagram is not **simpler** than a flow chart. A flow chart is a simpler (earlier) version of an Activity Diagram.

Flow charts were invented at least 20 years earlier and are commonly used by non-programmers to document workflows. Any business process where people have to make decisions can be described as a flow chart. So, for example, a clerk making decisions about how to file complicated information might have a flow chart on the wall.

Because a flow chart is a subset of an activity diagram, there's actually no decision to make. A flow chart naturally grows into an activity diagram if you need to add more complex descriptions.

Sparx have a [good explanation](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html) of the range of things you can describe in an Activity Diagram

Comment: This doesn't mention the similarity of UML 2 activity diagrams to colored Petri nets. I was going to answer, but didn't have the info handy.

Comment: @JimL I guess that state charts are more related to Petri nets. And AD are another descendant. I don't have a source of my truth, though ;-)

Comment: You say a flow chart is a subset of an activity diagram, user2864740 says an activity diagram is a subset of a flowchart. Personally I think the latter, as you've said yourself that flow charts predated activity diagrams - how can flow charts be a type of activity diagrams if the latter came later?

Comment: A flow chart is a "subset" of an activity diagram because it has simpler semantics. Activity Diagrams were created in UML to fill the same role.

Answer (score 10):

A [UML Activity Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) *is a type of* ["flowchart"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) .. in UML, with bells and whistles. There is no such thing as a "UML Flowchart". If using UML it is an Activity Diagram. If using something else, then something else is being used.

> [UML] Activity diagrams are *graphical representations of workflows of stepwise activities and actions* with support for choice, iteration and concurrency ..
>
> .. *Activity diagrams may be regarded as a form of flowchart.*

For better or worse, UML is a standardization. This is nice because it is well, "standardized", but also means that it is not appropriate for all tasks: the chosen "flowchart" model (and extensions thereof) might be a better fit for a particular problem/domain.

Comment: Is this answer almost 15 years out of date, for UML 1?

Comment: The first link says UML 1.

Comment: *"A UML Activity DIagram is a type of flowchart"* Isn't it the opposite? Meaning, a flowchart is a type of a UML Acitivity Diagram?

Answer (score 1):

An activity diagram assigns responsibilities to the objects involved in collaboration using swim lanes. So the diagram clearly shows the work to be done by each object in collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Both flowcharts and activity diagrams are used to show workflow but the activity diagram has a provision for assigning responsibility to the objects with the help of the swim lane concept.